# Can I use a (paired) t-test to compare the accuracies of classification models on a hold out test set?

Tags: classification, statistical-significance, t-test, validation, model-comparison

When comparing the Brier scores or logloss/cross-entropy for multiple models on a hold-out test set, how can I be sure the 'best' model doesn't just have the lowest loss due to chance? When can I be sure a model is better than another with statistical significance?

Say I have a classification problem with targets $y \in \{0, 1\}$ and I've got $M$ models that produce probability predictions $\hat{y}_i^m$, where $i$ represents the $i$th observation in the hold out data and $m$ designates what model the prediction came from. Let's also say the $M$ different models could be based on a logistic regression, boosted decision tree, neural net, etc, So I have no easy way of quantifying the models complexity in a degrees of freedom sense.

Can I do a bunch of pairwise t-tests to compare the means of the errors from each of the models? Because I am comparing predictions accross models on the same observations, can I use paired tests to reduce the variation? [And would this test be less powerful if the predictions between two models were negatively correlated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Paired_samples)? (not likely to be a problem in this setting).

For comparing Brier scores accross models, I would calculate the Brier loss of model $m$ for each observation $i$ as
$$
b_i^m = (y_i - \hat{y}_i^m)^2
$$
and for logloss I would calculate the loss as
$$
l_i^m = -1 \times \big( y_i\log\hat{y}_i^m + (1-y_i)\log(1-\hat{y}_i^m)\big)
$$

For two models $m_1$ and $m_2$, can I then use regular t-tests to compare the means of the vectors $b^{m_1}$ and $b^{m_2}$ or $l^{m_1}$ and $l^{m_2}$? Would this give me a reliable confidence interval for the difference in classification performance between the two models? In the case of the Brier scores, could I equivalently do an F-test to test the ratio of $b^{m_1}/b^{m_2} \neq 1$

**Another thought:**
Typically, when assessing models, we usually care about the *mean* of the errors or loss. So I think the t-test for the comparison of means of the Brier and logloss is appropriate. However, given that the logloss elements are not likely to be uniformly or symetrically distributed, perhaps a different test is more appropriate? Would a Mann–Whitney U test or Wilcoxon signed-rank test make more sense?

Comment: Of possible interest: https://jmlr.org/papers/v18/16-305.html. Benavoli, Alessio, et al. "Time for a change: a tutorial for comparing multiple classifiers through Bayesian analysis." The Journal of Machine Learning Research 18.1 (2017): 2653-2688.

Comment: Thank you @Dave. Whilst in this setting I don't have the correlation problem, there's some other interesting stuff to consider in that paper.

Comment: What about some information criteria, like AIC, BIC or [FIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focused_information_criterion)